# How can I set up state to allow one child component to render another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a main component which has two child components and six of each.

Something like this:

```
    <Main>
      <Component1 />
      <Component1 />
      <Component1 />
      <Component1 />
      <Component1 />
      <Component1 />
      <Component2 />
      <Component2 />
      <Component2 />
      <Component2 />
      <Component2 />
      <Component2 />
    </Main>
```

My goal is to be able to render a specific Component2 based on a toggle from Component 1.

So clicking the first Component1 would toggle the render of the first Component2

I've tried something like this in my main component:

```
  const [component2Visible, setcomponent2Visible] = useState([false, true, false, false, false, false])
```

But I don't think this is the right direction at all.

Comment: i think you should use a useReducer hook to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that I might employ:

```
// state variables to hold arguments to generate Component1 & Component2
// Component1 args have a prop named 'hideC2' (initially set to false)
const [comp1Args, setComp1Args] = useState([{hideC2: false, ...}, {hideC2: false, ....}, {}]);
const [comp2Args, setComp2Args] = useState([{}, {}, {}]);
.
.
.
// Iterate over the two args arrays to generate Components
// Use '.filter' on comp2Args to 'hide' those where 'hideC2' is set to true
return (
  <Main>
    {
      comp1Args.map((args, idx) => (
        <Component1
          key={idx}
          args={args}
          onToggleC2={() => setComp1Args(prev => {
            const curr = [...prev];
            curr[idx].hideC2 = !prev[idx].hideC2;
            return [...curr]
          })}
        />
      ))
    }
    {
      comp2Args
      .filter((el, idx) => (comp1Args[idx].hideC2 !== true))
      .map((args, idx) => (
        <Component2 key={idx} args={args}/>
      ))
    }
  </Main>
);
```